# Using explicit value passed to implicit parameter as new implicit value

Tags: scala, implicit

Consider this case class:

```
case class IntPrinter(implicit val i: Int) {
  def print()(implicit i: Int) = println(i)
}
```

I can instance it explicitly passing a value for the implicit argument like this:

```
val p = IntPrinter()(9)
```

I've been told in IRC that, from now on, the explicitly passed value will be implicitly passed to print when being called, but that's not the case:

```
p.print()
 error: could not find implicit value for parameter i: Int
```

Am I doing something wrong or I've misunderstood/been given incorrect information? Is there any way to achieve this?

---

**EDIT:** as a matter of fact it works as expected if I import `p._` like this:

```
import p._
p.print()
```

Which indeed prints `9`.

Is this the correct behaviour? Is using `import` as bad idea as it sounds? How do I workaround this?

Comment: The reason that importing `p._` works is because you're simply bringing the `i` from `case class IntPrinter(implicit val i: Int)` into scope.  But... that `i` is already "in scope" inside of the class; you don't need to do anything special to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed it's the correct behaviour. `implicit` values are only searched in current scope and calling `print` outside `IntPrinter` means it's not on the class scope (obviously) and the reason why I had to `import` it.

The correct way to do what I wanted:

```
case class IntPrinter(implicit val i: Int) {
  def print()(implicit i: Int) = println(i)
  def printProxy() = print()
}
```

And then calling `p.printProxy` behaves like I wanted it to behave (because `printProxy` is inside `IntPrinter`'s scope.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand.  Why is it that you need implicits here at all?  It seems that you could just as easily do this:

```
scala> case class IntPrinter(i: Int) { def print() = println(i) }
defined class IntPrinter

scala> val p = IntPrinter(9)
p: IntPrinter = IntPrinter(9)

scala> p.print()
9
```

or, if you really have use for `IntPrinter` taking an implicit:

```
scala> case class IntPrinter(implicit val i: Int) { def print() = println(i) }
defined class IntPrinter

scala> val p = IntPrinter()(9)
p: IntPrinter = IntPrinter(9)

scala> p.print()
9
```

Basically, in that case, you need not specify that it is implicit twice; when you declared it implicit the first time, that made `i` a member of the class, so you can continue to reference it throughout the rest of the class—just like you could with any other data member of a class.

Comment: It's just a minimal example, the way I mean to use it is more complicated. It's my fault anyways, I failed in expressing what I tried to achieve (see my answer.)

Comment: @kaoD But your answer still doesn't really make sense.  Why bother with `printProxy`?  Why not just access the `i` you already supplied when you created the object?  That's all that `printProxy` is doing, anyway....

Comment: Because, as I said, this is just a minimal example of what I wanted to achieve. I want syntactic sugar on a DSL I'm building which should transparently handle some implicit parameters (and pass them around to new instances of itself transparently too) without explicitly accessing them (for sanity and code clarity.) The value must be accessed only in a few cases while the rest of the time it must be invisible (as I said, I expect DSL clarity.)